# Web bluetooth Notification only few response

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-applications, web-bluetooth

I am learning use web bluetooth api to write web app and use chrome/chromium run it .
But the notification only response few times, I don't know why and how to debug it(to see what happened).

The bluetooth peripheral is an oximeter, use BLE to send real-time spo2, heart rate, etc. And my browser use Chromium 60.0.3112.78 built on Debian 9.1, running on Debian 9.1 (64 bit) .

Below is my javascript:

```
var serviceUuid = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
characteristicUuid = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ;
// Sorry, I hide the UUID.


document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    onStartButtonClick();
    }});

async function onStartButtonClick(){
    let options = {};
    options.acceptAllDevices = true;
    options.optionalServices = [serviceUuid];
    try{
        const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options);
        device.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', onDisconnected);
        console.log('Got device:', device.name);
        console.log('id:', device.id);

        console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
        const server = await device.gatt.connect();

        console.log('Getting Service...');
        const service = await server.getPrimaryService(serviceUuid);

        console.log('Getting Characteristic...');
        myCharacteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(characteristicUuid);

        myCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',
            handleNotifications);
        await myCharacteristic.startNotifications();
        console.log('> Notifications started');
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Argh! ' + error);
    }
}
async function disconnect(){
    await myCharacteristic.stopNotifications();
    onDisconnected();
}

function onDisconnected(event) {
  // Object event.target is Bluetooth Device getting disconnected.
  console.log('> Bluetooth Device disconnected');
}

var tmp_count=0;

async function handleNotifications(event) {
    // I will read data by Uint8Array.
    // var databuf = new Uint8Array(event.target.value.buffer);
    tmp_count++;
    console.log(tmp_count);
}
```

Console of chromium display:

```
03:41:49.893 (index):192 Connecting to GATT Server...
03:41:50.378 (index):195 Getting Service...
03:41:51.237 (index):198 Getting Characteristic...
03:41:51.359 (index):204 > Notifications started
03:41:51.781 (index):228 1
03:41:51.782 (index):228 2
03:42:22.573 (index):217 > Bluetooth Device disconnected
```

It's no response after `03:41:51.782 (index):228 2` , so I turn turn off oximeter.

What is the problem ? And what can I do ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that [Chrome supports Android, Chrome OS, macOS](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md) at this time.

Try using some of the tips on https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs such as `chrome://bluetooth-internals`, 
[nRF Connect for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) or [nRF Connect for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nrf-connect/id1054362403?mt=8)

If you can receive continuous notifications in those apps, but not in Chrome, there's a bug. Please file details on how to reproduce it, logs you've collected, there: https://crbug.com/new